# Set element as second in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some div's which are being dynamically loaded and depending on content - some may load faster, some may load later, but it is important for me to set them in specific order. So You could see what I mean:

```
<div id=1>text</div>
<div id=2>text2</div>
<div id=3>text3</div>
```

and if there is much more text they appear for example in this order:

```
<div id=1>text</div>
<div id=3>text3</div>
<div id=2>text2</div>
```

How to set proper order, no matter which div load firstly?

Comment: Create the (empty) divs first, then load the contents in the corresponding div. Without some code to go on, that's the most help i can give you. Alternatively, you can add the new div in the correct position in the DOM instead of appending it to the end.

Comment: There are a couple of approaches you can take. 1. You create a promise and wait for the promise to be resolved (which means wait for all the divs to be loaded) and then set the order. 2. As and when a div is created you recreate the order. Hope that helps

Comment: I like Tibos answer. Create the elements first and then append the content to each div.

Comment: That is why element id is there. You can use id to target content in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort them:

```
var sorted = $('div').get().sort(function(a, b){
        return a.id > b.id;
    }),
    $sorted = $(sorted).clone();

$('body').append($sorted); // do something
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4aGyD/6/

Comment: those id's were just exemplary.. they are not "1", "2" and "3".

Comment: @Mati Then create containers and load each div in to its corresponding container